# Mybatis No Getter Property

Tags: java, orm, mybatis, ibatis, ibatis.net

I'm working with Mybatis 3.2.6 and implementing a custom resulthandler.  I've done this before using a simple datatype parameter and have had no problems.  This time around I need to pass in several arguments... The signature I'm using is

```
session.select(statement, parameter, handler);
```

For parameter I've created a simple POJO to easily send in what I need.  It is as follows:

```
public class DifferenceParam {

private int current;
private int compare;

private String table;
private String comparator;

/**
 * Constructor excluding comparator.  Will default a value of
 * &quot;code&quot; to compare content on, e.g., <br/>
 * {@code select * from a minus select * from b where a.code = b.code } <br/>
 * @param table
 * @param current
 * @param compare
 */
public DifferenceParam(String table, int current, int compare) {
    this(table, "code", current, compare);
}

/**
 * Constructor providing a specific column to compare on, e.g. <br/>
 * {@code select * from a minus select * from b where a.[comparator] = b.[comparator] } <br/>
 * @param table
 * @param comparator
 * @param current
 * @param compare
 */
public DifferenceParam(String table, String comparator, int current, int compare) {
    this.table = table;
    this.comparator = comparator;
    this.current = current;
    this.compare = compare;
}

/** Appropriate setters and getters to follow **/
}
```

The handler implementation is irrelevant at the moment, because I get an exception well in advance...  The query I'm executing is:

```
<select id="getCodeSetModifications" parameterType="DifferenceParam" resultType="Code">
    select *
    from
    (
        select * from ${param.table} where revision_seq = #{param.current}

        minus

        select * from ${param.table} where revision_seq = #{param.compare}
    ) a, ${param.table} b
    where a.${param.comparator} = b.${param.comparator}
        and b.revision_seq = #{param.compare}
</select>
```

Here is the interface as well

```
public List<Code> getCodeSetModifications(@Param("param") DifferenceParam param);
```

The problem I'm having is that execution via a mapper e.g.,

```
session.getMapper(DifferenceParam.class);
```

works just fine, but when I invoke through a select on the session I get the following exception.

```
Error querying database.  Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'param' in 'class com.mmm.his.cer.cerval.uidifference.map.param.DifferenceParam'
Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'param' in 'class com.mmm.his.cer.cerval.uidifference.map.param.DifferenceParam'
```

I've debugged as far as I can go into Mybatis, but am having no luck.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried removing parameterType attribute from select? You should either use it and reference properties of parameter directly (${table} instead of ${param.table} or not use it.

Comment: You're exactly right!  In the original construction of the statement, before using a resultHandler I had like parameters with similar members so I was using the parameter name to differentiate, however I still have a few statements written in the form ${a.b} and #{a.b} and they work just fine.  Could this be a problem when only using a ResultHandler?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `session.getMapper(DifferenceParam.class);`, mybatis looks for `@Param` annotation and uses it's value in query.

When you invoke `session.select(statement, parameter, handler);`, such mapping doesn't occur.

Try to add `public DifferenceParam getParam() { return this; }` to DifferenceParam to workaround this.

Answer (score 0):

when the MyBatis query only have one param. Don't need `#{param.}` reference.

because it default use the only param.

so when u use `${param.table}`, it actually using `#{DifferenceParam.param.table}`.

because it think the `${param.}` inside of the `#{DifferenceParam.}`